Shifting Issue - Nexus 7 starts in 4th gear
I’m having some trouble with my Shimano Nexus 7-speed internal gear hub (from 2008) after reassembling my bike post-paint job. The hub seems to start in 4th gear, regardless of what gear I select on the shifter.
Here’s what’s happening:
Gear Behavior: When I set the shifter to 1st gear, the hub is actually in 4th. The hub doesn’t shift to 5th until I reach 3rd on the shifter, and the pattern continues like this across all gears.
Even with the shifter cable disconnected, the hub is in 4th gear.
The pulley on the cassette joint rotates smoothly, approximately 90° from min to max.
What I've Tried:

I opened up the hub, cleaned it, and re-lubricated all the internal
components.
Checked the shift cable, which appears to be intact and
properly installed.
I noticed that the alignment marks on the
cassette joint are missing, so I’ve been unable to use them for
precise adjustments.

Questions:

Could the issue be related to internal components such as the pawls or shift cam? If so, what should I inspect or test?
What steps can I take to correctly align or adjust the gears without the alignment marks?
Is there something else I might have overlooked that could be causing this misalignment in gear shifting?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I’m really eager to get my bike back in working order.
Thanks in advance for your help!
